# Is there an option in ReSharper to add a blank line after a closing bracket

Tags: c#, resharper

I would like to add a blank line after a closing bracket inside of a method. I cannot find a setting for this. Here is some sample code.

What I have:

```
if (something != null) {
    something = 1;
}    
var andThen = 2;
```

What I want:

```
if (something != null) {
    something = 1;
}

var andThen = 2;
```

**edit:** I have version 8.1.23.546.

Comment: As far as I know, no.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just wanted to comment that this will be fixed in version 2017.3 of R# and that it is already fixed in R# 2017.3 EAP 7 which can be downloaded from [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/eap/).

> Updated C# Formatting Style options for blank lines before and after statements with blocks, control transfer as well as multiline statements.

This can be configured in the R# options under Formatting Style => Blank Lines => Before/After statements with child blocks.

Comment: Yay! IDEA might have the option too shortly.

Comment: I just installed this and it works great! Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 10):

No, that is not possible in ReSharper, at least not in version 7.0.1.

There is nothing of the kind in **Formatting Style -> Braces Layout**, nothing in **Formatting Style -> Blank Lines** and nothing in **Formatting Style -> Line Breaks and Wrapping**.

Comment: The feature request is here - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-70304 - feel free to vote it up!

Comment: And 8 years after that feature request was submitted, still nothing is done with it, so I wouldn't hold my breath.