# ReSharper empty line after curly braces inside method

Tags: resharper, stylecop

Is it possible to force ReSharper code cleanup to place empty line after curly brace inside the method, to automatically fix StyleCop SA1513 warning?

e.g.
before formatting:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return View(model);
}
var user = await GetCurrentUserAsync();
```

after formatting:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return View(model);
}

var user = await GetCurrentUserAsync();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an option in ReSharper to add a blank line after a closing bracket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22175548/is-there-an-option-in-resharper-to-add-a-blank-line-after-a-closing-bracket)